# Google Api Error: Invalid request - APK is marked as debuggable

Tags: android, expo, apk, fastlane, eas

When submitting app through Expo EAS on the internal track, the APK build seems to succeed, but the following error appears for submission:

> `Google Api Error: Invalid request - APK is marked as debuggable`

Before posting the question I tried several things.

1. Add `debuggable="true"` to the `<Application` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` in both `main` and `debug` folders.
2. Check `build.gradle` and `app.json` files with another clean Expo 47 project.
3. Check incremented version numbers
4. Check Expo doctor (fixed all, except one warning)

Please see the screenshot for the submission logs.

[image]

**These are the build step logs.**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by removing `"developmentClient": true,` from the `build` profile in `eas.json`

```
"build": {
    "development":{
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    ...
}
```

By doing that I also had to remove `debuggable="true"` from the `<Application` tag in my `AndroidManifest.xml` files.